# How to get most popular tweets without query?

Tags: python, twitter

I'm using a Python API, and I want to retrieve the most popular tweets from Twitter, without a specific query. I'm want all popular tweets, not just those related to a certain search term.

```
api = twitter_connect()

for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search, q='query',result_type='popular').items(5):
    print(tweet.text)
```

Unfortunately, in the Twitter API, the `query` parameter is required. How can I fetch the most popular tweets independent of a search query?

Comment: Your question makes no sense. *How can I find out what tweets are most popular without a query that asks which tweets are most popular?* is not a question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to try the Twitter API [trends/place](http://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/trends/place) endpoint. From the docs:

> [trends/place](http://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/trends/place)
>    returns the top 50 trending topics for a specific [WOEID (Yahoo! Where On Earth ID)](http://developer.yahoo.com/geo/geoplanet/)

```
trends1 = api.trends_place(1) # Global information is available by using 1 as the WOEID .
data = trends1[0]
trends = data['trends']

for trend in trends[0:5]: # Get only the first 5 popular trending tweets
    print trend
```

output (example, at the time of this posting):

```
{u'url': u'http://twitter.com/search?q=%23GagaCoachella', u'query': u'%23GagaCoachella', u'tweet_volume': 83882, u'name': u'#GagaCoachella', u'promoted_content': None}
{u'url': u'http://twitter.com/search?q=%23FallonStylesSNL', u'query': u'%23FallonStylesSNL', u'tweet_volume': 538109, u'name': u'#FallonStylesSNL', u'promoted_content': None}
{u'url': u'http://twitter.com/search?q=%22Happy+Easter%22', u'query': u'%22Happy+Easter%22', u'tweet_volume': 485731, u'name': u'Happy Easter', u'promoted_content': None}
{u'url': u'http://twitter.com/search?q=%23Bug%C3%BCnHay%C4%B1r%C3%87%C4%B1kacak', u'query': u'%23Bug%C3%BCnHay%C4%B1r%C3%87%C4%B1kacak', u'tweet_volume': 25544, u'name': u'#Bug\xfcnHay\u0131r\xc7\u0131kacak', u'promoted_content': None}
{u'url': u'http://twitter.com/search?q=%23JavierDuarte', u'query': u'%23JavierDuarte', u'tweet_volume': 67939, u'name': u'#JavierDuarte', u'promoted_content': None}
```

Refer to the [documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/trends/place) for more options to customize the query.